# Scheme: variable required in this context

Tags: scheme

I use mit-scheme compiler for learning Scheme.

The program which I write must compute equation roots via Vieta theorem.

```
(define (roots p q x-begin x-end)
    (let ((x1 0.0) (x2 0.0))
        (set! (x1 x-begin)) ; Error here Variable required in this context: (x1 x-begin)
        (set! (x2 x-begin))

        ; ...  
    )   
)
```

I guess that error concerned with static scope in Scheme.
What i do wrong?

P.S. Sorry for my english.

Comment: A more "natural" start would be `(let ((x1 x-begin) (x2 x-begin))...`. (Don't think of `let` as a way of declaring variables.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how you intend to calculate the roots but I can provide some advise regarding Scheme syntax, this is incorrect:

```
(set! (x1 x-begin))
```

It should be:

```
(set! x1 x-begin)
```

In general, using `set!` should be avoided whenever possible: in Scheme we try real hard to write programs that follow the functional-programming paradigm, and that includes not reassigning variables.